# How to Combine Three table with aggregate functions in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables one is SaleinfoTB second table is StarReadingEndReading and 3rd table is ExpenseinfoTb in the SaleinfoTB table i  want to sum TotalBill Column and StartReadingEndReading table i want to sum ActualSell Column and Plus both Sum and mins from ExpenseintoTB Table Column Amount

select SUM((SaleinfoTB.TotalBill)+ SUM(StartReadingEndReading.ActualSell)) -

(SUM(ExpenseinfoTB.Amount)) from SaleinfoTB,SaleinfoTB,ExpenseinfoTB

where SaleinfoTB.Date=StartReadingEndReading.ReadingDate

and  ExpenseinfoTB.ExpenseDate=SaleinfoTB.Date

and ExpenseinfoTB.ExpenseDate=StartReadingEndReading.ReadingDate

Comment: Can you more clearly describe what you are trying to do?  Just posting a code snippet doesn't give us enough information to answer your question.

Comment: first off use explicit JOINS like  INNER JOIN for this matter.... 2ndly what's the issue here?

Comment: Sorry for my question which is not clear i have edit my post and add some information about my post

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting at is how to get the sum of each item before you do the addition/subtraction

```
SELECT (ISNULL(SaleinfoTB.SumTotalBill,0) 
    + ISNULL(StartReadingEndReading.SumActualSell,0)) 
    - ISNULL(ExpenseinfoTB.SumAmount,0)
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(TotalBill) SumTotalBill, [Date] 
            FROM SaleinfoTB  
            Group By [Date])SaleinfoTB
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(ActualSell) SumActualSell, ReadingDate 
            FROM StartReadingEndReading  
            Group By ReadingDate)StartReadingEndReading
        ON SaleinfoTB.[Date]=StartReadingEndReading.ReadingDate
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) SumAmount, ExpenseDate 
            FROM ExpenseinfoTB  
            Group By ExpenseDate)ExpenseinfoTB
        ON ExpenseinfoTB.ExpenseDate=SaleinfoTB.[Date]
```

Comment: Thank you it is working but not Showing  the result  data

Comment: It's showing no rows?  Is one of those tables guaranteed to always have a row for the date?  You may need the INNER JOIN to be changed to LEFT JOIN but it depends on which tables have the data.  If you can edit your post to include sample data I can probably help more.

Comment: Table date was not matching that's way result was not showing now it's fine